# C++11: will lambda malloc space each time when it declared?

Tags: c++11

Just wanna clearify that: will the lambda malloc space each time and free itself when block ends?
for example

```
void func() {
    auto lambda = [] (args) { expressions; }
    static auto s_lambda = [] (args) { expressions; }
}
```

where lambda() will be malloc-ed to ram each time I call func(), while s_lamda() will not?

In such case, the performance of lambda() will be slightly worse than s_lambda() if they have a really huge func-body?

Comment: Why do you think it would need to be malloc'ed? Why won't the compiler just keep it on the stack frame of `func()`?

Comment: You're showing lambdas that don't capture anything, there's nothing to allocate for them.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know: the implementation of the lambda. I just 'imagine' that for each time a lambda is declared, the whole func-body will be malloced into ram just like a variable.

Comment: The function body is just a block of code. It will live in executable memory. `lambda` is a local variable, with an opaque implementation-dependent type, which has no reason to allocate anything from the heap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lambda object will take up memory, but not the way you're thinking.

```
auto lambda = [] (args) { expressions; }
```

gets translated by the compiler into something like (very much simplified)

```
struct __lambda {
    auto operator()(args) { expressions; }
};

__lambda lambda;
```

Because of how C++ works, every object has a strictly positive size, and `sizeof(lambda)` will be at least one. Depending on what your lambda captures, those captures may be stored as fields in the compiler-generated class as well, and in that case, the lambda will take up more memory to hold those captures.

But the actual body of its internal `operator()` function is something that gets compiled, it's not something that gets created at run-time again and again and again. And if your lambda does not actually use any captured data, the storage of at least one byte is likely to get optimised away.

Comment: Thanks. The example is very illustrative. You are right and I just realize that if the func-body were malloced at run-time, then the whole c++11 would becomes a scripting language. Imagine something like: ((string) lambda).replace("int i", "float f")  :P