# C++: nested lambda function refer same address of passed parameter

Tags: c++, lambda, nested, pass-by-value

I studied lambdas and noticed some strange things when nesting lambda functions.

```
int x{10}; // assume x has 0x1 address here
cout << "SCOPE: x address:  " << &x << endl; // showing 0x1 for x address
auto show =
    [](int x) {
        cout << "SHOW: x address: " << &x << endl;
    };
cout << "SCOPE: show-lambda address: " << &show << endl;
show(x); // showing 0x2 for x address
auto fv =
    [x, show]() {
        cout << "FV  : x address: " << &x << " " << endl; // 0x3
        cout << "FV  : show-lambda address:" << &show << endl;
        show(x); // showing 0x4 for x address
    };
auto fr =
    [&x, show]() {
        cout << "FR  : x address: " << &x << " " << endl; // showing 0x1 for x address
        cout << "FR  : show-lambda address:" << &show << endl;
        show(x); // showing 0x4 for x address - WHY???
    };
fv();
fr();
```

```
SCOPE: x address:  0x39f95c
SCOPE: show-lambda address: 0x39f95b
SHOW: x address: 0x39f928
FV  : x address: 0x39f950
FV  : show-lambda address:0x39f954
SHOW: x address: 0x39f8f8
FR  : x address: 0x39f95c
FR  : show-lambda address:0x39f948
SHOW: x address: 0x39f8f8
```

`x` got address `a1 = 0x39f95c`.

`x` is passed by value (its value is copied) into `SHOW` lambda so it shows new address `a2 = 0x39f95b`.

We call `FV` lambda capturing `x` by value (its value is copied). So inside `FV` it has new address `a3 = 0x39f950`.

From `FV` we call `SHOW` lambda. `x` (from `FV`'s scope) is passed by value so inside `SHOW` we get new address for `X - a4 = 0x39f8f8`

We call `FR` lambda capturing `x` by reference (no value copy here). So inside `FR` `x` has address `a1 = 0x39f95c` - fair enough.

From `FR` we call `SHOW` lambda. `x` (`x` reference?) (from `FV`'s scope) is passed by value so inside `SHOW` we get new... Wait what? `x`'s address here is `0x39f8f8 = a4`.

I do not understand that. As I understand, lambdas are compiled as some kind of classes so they are objects in memory. You can see I also logged `SHOW` lambda addresses inside `FV` and `FR`. They are different. This means that these `SHOW` lambdas are different objects so instances of `x` inside them should be different. But it could not lead me to any conclusion.

Can anyone explain how we get same addresses inside `FR` inside `SHOW`?

Comment: Each time you create a lambda, it gets compiled to a completely unique(different) compiler specific class type with some already overloaded operator(s).

Comment: Do you know what a stack is, how it works, and how it's relevant here?

Comment: @Jason Seems like I mentioned that in question. Not including 'some already overloaded operators'.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know that while calling a function, memory for this function is allocated on stack which is part of memory of the process. As I understand, when I call my lambdas, memory is allocated on stack. 
Still no idea how to answer my question. SHOW lambdas inside FV and FR are different instances. How does they hold same address for X?

Comment: what exactly do you not understand or expected or desire to get differently about the output?

Comment: btw what is line 95 ?!?

Comment: `x` is passed by value here `auto show = [](int x)`. YOu need no lambdas to see same effect. Seems like you confused yourself with same named variables that are just copies of each other but not identical (as in "have the same address"). If you want to pass a reference then pass a reference `auto show = [](int& x)`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number line 95 is fr() - sorry for that, line numbers are irrelevant (copy-paste issue), I edited the question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number on the last line of output I expected some new address for X inside FR-SHOW call stack. But I found the same address X had in FV-SHOW call stack.

Comment: i have tio admit, even after writing the answer I am still not sure which output exactly you expected to be different

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I expected some new address for parameter during third call to `show(x)`. But in the last line of output I got same address I got 3 lines before during second call to `show(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expect different objects that are just copies of the `x` in the outer most scope to be the same object.

Here is your code with using differnt names for the copies:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
  
    int x {10};
    cout << "SCOPE: x address:  " << &x << endl; // this is x 
    auto show = [](int y) 
    {
        cout << "SHOW: y address: " << &y << endl; 
    };
    cout << "SCOPE: show-lambda address: " << &show << endl;
    show(x); // copy x
    auto fv = [ z = x, show]()  // copy x
    {
        cout << "FV  : z address: " << &z << " " << endl; 
        show(z); // copy x again 
    };
    auto fr = [&x, show]()
    { 
        cout << "FR  : x address: " << &x << " " << endl; //  this is x, because captured as reference
        show(x); // copy x 
    };
    fv();
    fr();
}
```

In the output though there is still 3 different `y` because `show` is called 3 times (and twice is just happens to end up at the same address, but thats just by chance:

```
SCOPE: x address:  0x7ffe1f6d067c
SCOPE: show-lambda address: 0x7ffe1f6d067b
SHOW: y address: 0x7ffe1f6d0644
FV  : z address: 0x7ffe1f6d0670 
SHOW: y address: 0x7ffe1f6d0624
FR  : x address: 0x7ffe1f6d067c 
SHOW: y address: 0x7ffe1f6d0624
```

As mentioned in a comment, its not just "by chance" that the same adress is printed. When a function returns its stack is freed and can be used by the next function called. You can see same effect with this example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    int x = 42;
    std::cout << &x << "\n";
}

int main() {
    foo();
    foo();
}
```

[Possible output](https://godbolt.org/z/WsqMdqxbs):

```
0x7ffddcc6fd9c
0x7ffddcc6fd9c
```

Comment: >>>there is still 3 different y because show is called 3 times - I think exactly the same because I understand why - y is a copy of parameter we pass.

>>>and twice is just happens to end up at the same address, but thats just by chance - Probably that's what I wanted to hear, thanks.

Comment: Not exactly by chance. I bet if `show(x);` was the next statement, the address of `show::x` would be the same as the previous ones. When an object gets out of scope, it's memory is available for new objects. As long as invoking new functions generates similar enough machine code, the stack frame remains similar. But again, this is still UB; no guarantees.

Comment: @Red.Wave if `show(x)` was the next statement to which one? In the end of the day, I'm still confused. Different addresses (log in my code proves that) of `show` lambda inside `fv()` and `fr()` means different stack frames were allocated for these lambdas. And how different stack frames contain same address for `x` confuses me.

Comment: @Red.Wave I would accept that if `show` lambdas addresses were the same. I could think about it as memory for `show` call from `fv()` were deallocated and were allocated for `show` from `fr()`. But I do not see if it is the case.

Comment: @VladZhukovsky, now that you have changed the names it is much easier. Stack frame allocation for each object takes place upon its initialization. Execution of `fv()` and `fr()` happens at a different context than their initialization. So `x` and `z` are far apart from `y`. State of stack frame before and after call to `fr()` is the same. And since no new object has been pushed over the stack, same is the state befor call to `fv()`; thus new `y` is placed on the same location as previous `y`. No go ahead and call `show(x)` once again. New `y` won't be more than 8 bytes away from last `y`.

Comment: @Red.Wave I am not sure I follow everything you said, sorry. But I think I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523761/c11-will-lambda-malloc-space-each-time-when-it-declared. After lambda was compiled into some struct/class, its body is contained by one and only stack frame. So program goes to one memory block each time you call lambda. That's why passed-by-value parameters are put by same address. Sounds right?

Comment: @VladZhukovsky , I am not sure, I understand you correctly. But consider lambda as a structure with a function call operator, defined and instantiated at once. You can define an aggregate class with same functionality; but that would be much longer, less convenient. The points of construction and invocation are distinct and probably distant too. So, the location capture list is totally irrelevant to function call operator's stack frame. If the capture list doesn't contain references, it is often safe to return the lambda as the  result or place it on heap by putting it into a container.

Comment: @RedWave they need not be distant. You can declare and define classes insisde functions. It would be just much more verbose